# Multiple threads increment shared variable without locks but return "unexpected" output

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrent-programming

I'm invoking 100 threads, and each threads should increment a shared variable 1000 times. Since I'm doing this without using mutex locks, the expected output should NOT be 100000. However, I'm still getting 100000 every time.

This is what I have

```
volatile unsigned int count = 0;  
void *increment(void *vargp);

int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "Before: count = %d\n", count);

    int j;
    // run 10 times to test output
    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        // reset count every time
        count = 0;

        int i;
        // create 100 theads
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            pthread_t thread;

            Pthread_create(&thread, NULL, increment, NULL);
            Pthread_join(thread, NULL);
        }

        fprintf(stdout, "After: count = %d\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}          

void *increment(void *vargp) {
    int c;

    // increment count 1000 times
    for (c = 0; c < 1000; c++) {
        count++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pthread_join() function suspends execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates ([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html)). After you create each thread, you wait for it to run and terminate. The threads never execute concurrently. Thus, there's no race condition